# $S$ is a basis for it's own span if and only if it's a countable orthonormal set

Tags: hilbert-spaces

A section on Hilbert Spaces makes the following claim (item A):
[image]

Obvious if $S$ is orthonormal it must be linearly independent and thus be a base for the span. The converse doesn't seem true. For example i could pick two non-orthogonal vector that generate a plane.

I must be missing something here.

Comment: Unless "basis" means "orthonormal basis" for this author, it's not you who's missing something.

Comment: What does $\lor S$ denote?

Comment: I guess it's using the word 'basis' here as '*Hilbert basis*', i.e. orthonormal system whose orthogonal set is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Berci is right. I checked and he requires the basis to be orthonormal in his definition.

Comment: I hope the author also required Hilbert spaces to be separable, as the result fails otherwise.